# HTML/CSS : Focus a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to focus each "p" tag separately when I click on it, like a CSS "focus:" on an input. The problem is that the selector "focus" doesn't work on paragraphs, here is an exemple :

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <p>Some Content 1</p>
    <p>Some Content 2</p>
    <p>Some Content 3</p>
    <p>Some Content 4</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#myDiv p:focus {background-color:red;}
```

How can I find an alternative solution to make it work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add `tabindex` to the `p` tag to achieve this

```css
#myDiv p:focus {
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    <p tabindex="0">Some Content 1</p>
    <p tabindex="0">Some Content 2</p>
    <p tabindex="0">Some Content 3</p>
    <p tabindex="0">Some Content 4</p>
</div>
```

Jquery solution will be

```js
click = false;
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if(!($(e.target).is('p'))) {
    $('p').css('background', 'transparent')
  }
})
$('p').click(function() {
    $('p').css('background', 'transparent');
    $(this).css('background', 'red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>Some Content 1</p>
  <p>Some Content 2</p>
  <p>Some Content 3</p>
  <p>Some Content 4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice!  I had no idea you could do that.  I was going to suggest a javascript solution.

Comment: Really nice alternative, I didn't know you could do that! But I'm searching for a javascript solution if possible, because I'm running on drupal 7 and I can't change directly into the class for some fields.

Comment: @Lance can you post the javascript solution it would be useful too :)

Comment: If you are okay with jquery i can give you an answer @Sia

Comment: Beat you to it @Lance :)

Comment: @Akshay and Lance thanks for your help it's perfect :D!

Comment: You should post your answer @Lance a javascript solution will be great

Comment: I'm having trouble with the pure js script anyway.  For some stupid reason, getElementsByTagName isn't working.  If I get it, I'll post it.

Comment: Yes.  I'm sure it's something stupid that I'm missing.  I'm trying to get the collection to loop through and reset all the backgrounds before setting the most recently clicked one to red.  Without that, they all just stay in the "focus" color.

Comment: If you share the code i can help to maybe in a jsfiddle but i am not that good with javascript @Lance

Comment: I got it.  Thanks.  Posted below.

Comment: Great @Lance you can also add a click event to body so that the background disappears when you click on the body too

Comment: After 1 hour of google searches with directives for focus and a ton of other solutions, this helped out! Thanks! I had a combobox and an input field that worked great with focus using @ViewChild and setTimeout(() => this.inputFieldElement.nativeElement.focus(), 0), but my errorMessage did not get focus using the same approach.. adding a tabindex to my <div> tag made it happen!

Comment: Wow @TomasAndersen glad i could help you out :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a javascript only version:

```js
function highlight(theP)
{
 var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
 {
  x[i].style.background = "";
 }

 theP.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    <p onclick="highlight(this);">Some Content 1</p>
    <p onclick="highlight(this);">Some Content 2</p>
    <p onclick="highlight(this);">Some Content 3</p>
    <p onclick="highlight(this);">Some Content 4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `onclick`.

Comment: @klenium Why is that?